# CSS width and margin as percent not behaving as I want

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body {
background-color: red;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
* { margin: 0; padding:0; }
.topbar {
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 50%;
   background-color: green;
}
.fill {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
.container {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>
<div class="topbar">
  "topbar
  <div class="fill">
    "fill"
    <div class="container">
     "container" 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why "fill" is not taking the complete 50% of its containing element "topbar" on the screen?

Why "container" is not taking complete 50% of its containing element "fill" on the screen?

Separate Question:
My goal is to create a layout which can fit *almost* all screens desktops/laptops. I am not focusing on phone screen layouts for now. I am trying to use width and height as percentages for my layout. Please suggest if that is the right approach or point me to alternatives.

Comment: I would look into using and modifying an existing responsive framework like Skeleton CSS: http://getskeleton.com/. Using that framework, you just assign classes to create various widths expressed as a fraction of the screen (e.g. columns).

Answer (score 0):

Because the body's height is uncertain.You need a parent dom

Comment: The reason I was using percent was since different screens have different width/height. I thought somehow it will be detected and used. There onwards my percent specs will take effect. If that is not how it works, Then how do I detect height/width at runtime?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the height. Unless you need to fit everything in the viewable area of the screen, it doesn't really matter that much. Instead, focus on the width. If you do need to worry about the height, the easiest way is to detect the screens using CSS media queries.

Comment: Or you could use jQuery with something like `$(window).height()`.

Comment: thanks. I am trying your jquery suggestion. Also, as you suspected, I want to use the full viewable area of screen for one of my rendering. Just curious, have you tried the jQuery test in the past yourself. Was wondering if that suggestion indeed will work. I am trying myself anyways

Comment: I made it work somehow. Not sure if thats the correct way of doing things. But the only change that I did in the code I posted above was to change from min-height to height. I did not set height of any element using jQuery or explicitly in the code. This was the behavior that I was expecting in the first place. But due to some answers posted for this question, I am confused (how this works). If anybody has the time/patience please explain

Answer (score 0):

When you use percentage for height and width, it's important that the parent element has specific size in pixel...

in this case "topbar" class should have size in pixel